# Beautifulsoup Finding HTML Tags with certain text

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup and Python for web scraping.

For example, I have the following html text

```
<body>
    <h5 class="h-bar">
        <b class="caret"></b>
        Model 11111
        Set Item
    </h5>
</body>
```

Now, I'm trying to find any  tag whose text contains the word "Set Item."

I tried the following:

```
soup.find_all('h5', text="Set Item")
```

I expected to get this:

```
    <h5 class="h-bar">
        <b class="caret"></b>
        Model 11111
        Set Item
    </h5>
```

However, this returns None.. I am not sure why beautiful soup cannot find the match..
What Should I do to detect the tag with "Set Item" in its text?

Comment: Because there is a nested tag in that `h5` element you cannot match on `text` there. I think this is a dupe of a question I answered before.

Comment: So use `for h5 in soup.find_all('h5', text=False): if 'Set Item' in h5.text:`, or use a custom function for the search: `soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'h5' and 'Set Item' in t.text):`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: could you link to that answer? This is the top google result and I don't see your answer anywhere near the top of search results. If it contains a more complete answer it would be nice to be able to get there from here

Comment: @BenKushigian: see the duplicate banner on this post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Woops, didn't see the top one :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am a BeautifulSoup newbie as well. There must be a better way, but this one seems to work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def predicate(element):
    pattern = re.compile(r'Set Item')
    return element.name == u'h5' and element.find(text=pattern) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html').read())
    found = soup.find_all(predicate) # found: a list of elements
    print 'Found:', found
```

Please excuse the open().read() chain. I was just being lazy.

Output:

```
Found: [<h5 class="h-bar">
<b class="caret"></b>
        Model 11111
        Set Item
    </h5>]
```

## Update

Predicate does not need to employ regular expression:

```
def predicate(e):
    return e and e.name == u'h5' and 'Set Item' in e.text
```